# Multiattack and Modifiers

Tags: dnd-5e, multiattack

If a monster has Multiattack, do I have to add the modifiers to each attack roll?

For example, the Redbrand Ruffians have Multiattack (they can make two attacks) and +4 to hit when using a shortsword. I know I have to make two different rolls, but do I have to add the modifier to both of the attack rolls?

Comment: Good first question by the way!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Use the attack bonus for the shortsword attacks if that is what they use to attack

> Multiattack The ruffian makes two melee attacks

Since there is no modifier or anything listed under the multiattack section, use the modifier listed under the shortsword section since that is what you are actually using to make the melee attacks.

> Shortsword. Melee Weapon Attack: +4 to hit...

When you use multiattack you are still making multiple melee attack rolls. And each melee attack roll you make should get an applicable bonus to hit. This means that, for *each* of the two melee attack you make with the shortsword (as part of your multiattack), you will roll a d20 and add +4 to it.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't phrase the question well enough. My question is: When the npc takes the attack action, it says +4 to hit. Multiattack says the npc can make up to two attacks. Do I have to add the +4 to both, to one, or to none?

Comment: @Leia No that was my fault! I misread your question. I think I addressed part if it in the current edit, but let me edit it a bit more and let me know if it is better.

Comment: @Leia does that address your question now? Anything that remains confusing?

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure, because when a PC makes two attacks the modifiers apply to the first.

Comment: @Leia you might be confusing this with PCs dual wielding although the attack modifiers still apply. comments are not the right place for this kind of discussion though so you might want to jump into [general chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) once you have enough reputation (it shouldn't take long)